Unity WebGL Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed
I have a Unity webGL training app.  The app can run on any PC.  It runs a number of php scripts on the server to logon and update test scores etc in a database with mysqli.  It checks whether a user is already in the database before adding data etc.  It runs perfectly from the editor.
I added:
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
... to .htaccess on the server.  I still get an error: "Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed"
The post Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?  is helpful but how do I allow any domain?
Help please.
I've tried various changes to .htaccess and tried modifying the scripts.  I still get the error.  The Unity manual suggestion here doesn't seem to work:  https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/webgl-networking.html
I've found that using a CORS proxy server works.  Is there any way to avoid this?
